# access denied for user root, mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1045

when i am using sequel pro to connect to a remote database, the server says access denied. I am 100% percent sure that the username and password are correct. I also try to use phpmyadmin to connect to the server, it works. I don't know what happened when I am using sequel pro to connect to the server.

Comment: OK, i solved the problem,
1. add a row in mysql.user with root access, and make the host to be my ip address

Comment: 2. flush privilege (however in this step, i get an "mysql.servers table not found" error. after a quick googling, this is due to the absence of servers table.)

Comment: 3.run the following sql statement will solve the problem.
CREATE TABLE `servers` (
  `Server_name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Host` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Username` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Password` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Port` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Socket` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Wrapper` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Owner` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Server_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='MySQL Foreign Servers table'

Comment: 4. run "flush privilege;" again
5. done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql authentication depends not only of login + password but of host too.
create another user with login "root" and any password you want and necessary (or any "%") host

Comment: hi, zerkms, thanks very much for the help, but the sequel pro only shows the error after i restarted the server this morning. this used to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your MySQL server probably only allows root logins on localhost, as I believe is default.

Since phpMyAdmin is bouncing the connection through a webserver running on the SQL server, the root connection will appear to be coming from localhost and be accepted.

Comment: thanks very much. this helps me a lot in my understanding of the current problem. but the sequel pro used to work on my laptop, this problem happened after i restarted the server. something even more weird is that my teammates can still access the mysql server even after i have restarted the server. any help?

Comment: which computer is the server running on?

Comment: it is a internal server running mac os x.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the servers table was already there. Turned out sequel pro needed to have the socket url specified.

So log in to terminal in mysql:

```
mysql -u root
```

Then get mysql status by typing `\s`

Find what your UNIX socket path is, copy that and paste to the "socket" field in Sequel Pro.

That did it for me.

Comment: * log in to mysql in terminal of course, not the other way around ;)